Why print(f"{variable = }") in Python 3.12 also prints numpy type?
I noticed, that with Python 3.12 and a numpy.float64 when I simply do a
x = numpy.sqrt(3) # type is <class 'numpy.float64'> now
print(f"{x = }")

# this is printed
>>>x = np.float64(1.7320508075688772)

# in Python 3.11 this was printed
>>>x = 1.7320508075688772

I find this rather annoying, is there a cure for this behaviour?
Thanks a lot!

Is it the same numpy version?

Oh, my bad. I didn't check that on my old machine. With Python 3.11 I had numpy 1.23.5 and now with 3.12 it's 2.0.0.

Ahhh, I think I found it: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/2.0.0-notes.html. I will use np.set_printoptions(legacy="1.25") for now. I understand why they are doing it, but I don't like it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78634132.

This question is similar to: How to stop numpy floats being displayed as "np.float64"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I solved my problem, I wont do anything else here until I have a different problem.

This is due to numpy 2 as mentionned in the comments. You could specify the print format:
>>>print(f"{x = :f}")
x = 1.732051
>>>print(f"{x = :.16f}")
x = 1.7320508075688772

